# Different action depending on the device (HTML,JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, pdf, fancybox

I'm making a site and have a little problem with fancybox pdf scrolling on ipad.
To fix this I want to make another action when people are viewing my page on the ipad,... .

This is the code I have

```
<a href="http://xx.xx/xx.pdf" class="pdf">Open pdf</a>
```

this is the script

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},
Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},
Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
},
any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
}
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".pdf").fancybox({
           'type'  : 'iframe',
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        iframe : {
            preload: false
        }
    });

    $(".pdf").click(function() {
    if( isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Android() ){
             e.preventDefault();
            $('.pdf').attr('target', '_blank');
            $(".pdf").removeClass("pdf");
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

When I open the site op my ipad it doesn't open the page in a new tab but it keeps the original action of opening in a fancybox. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You've got all the code you need to identify an ipad in your code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should detect only the iPad if it is the only device you are targeting for modifications...

`navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        $(".pdf").fancybox({
            'type': 'iframe',
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            iframe: {
                preload: false
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".pdf").attr("target", "_blank");
    }
});
```